# updating a doc couchdb

Tags: couchdb, nosql

Please bear with me if my question is simple, I'm so new to couchDB:

I have this document:

```
{
   Name : Raju
   age : 23
   Designation : Designer
}
```

How can I update my document to:

```
{
   Name : Raju
   age : 23
}
```

Can I use `insert`for the document with my desired data which is `{Name : Raju, age : 23}` object? Does it delete `Designation` field?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can do that, CouchDB does not attempt to merge updates, just updates the doc to whatever you sent it. Please take a moment to read http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/intro/api.html#documents
It is a very simple, well written bunch of examples. I would encourage you to read the couchdb docs first if you new to it.